# Unable to use nyc/istanbul for code coverage

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I am using `nightwatch` for selenium based tests, but when I use `nyc nightwatch`, it only reports the test code and their 100% coverage. **This is my primary blocker right now**. How do I get the coverage? Basically, I want to get this as a report in Jenkins CI ultimately.

Additionally, I thought to test with my UTs as well for which I am using `jest`. Normally, `"test": "jest --coverage"` will list the coverage properly with all the tested code. So when I give `nyc npm run test` it gives me same coverage, which is good. But the moment I run with only `nyc jest`, it returns 100% coverage for `jest.config.js`!!

I don't have `mocha` or `grunt` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since jest uses nyc under the hood, there is no reason to use them together. You can call jest with the `--coverage` flag and tell it which reports to use in your config, as defined in the config:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/vendor/**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      "jest-junit"
    ]
  }
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring